# solve matrix of symbolic equations without using loop

Tags: matlab, matrix, equation

I have an equation denoted as 'a' in the code. I am trying to solve this equation for different values. When I use solve(eq), it does not solve the problem and gives an error. The solution must be in the form 4 by 1, I guess.

```
syms x y t
a = 3*x^2 + 2*y +7;
b = rand(4,2);
eq = subs(a,{x,y},{b(:,1)*t,b(:,2)*t,})
eq = (114796936454163404704655535315507*t^2)/81129638414606681695789005144064 + (7027663972423957*t)/4503599627370496 + 7
(2049112225923387932688645929427*t^2)/20282409603651670423947251286016 + (730715964868191*t)/4503599627370496 + 7
(8261891359675172983093065745827*t^2)/20282409603651670423947251286016 + (4185582312538139*t)/2251799813685248 + 7
(95262076673210081160325846940403*t^2)/81129638414606681695789005144064 + (1746749665163685*t)/1125899906842624 + 7
solve(eq)
```

PS: Since I run this code inside a different function, I am trying to save time here by not using loops.

Comment: I have no idea what the code is supposed to do, but it solves `(14170483253595195*t)/9007199254740992==0` and returns the correct answer which is `0`

Comment: When I simplified, I missed your point. it does not solve 4 equations.

Comment: Everything you put into `solve` is `(114796936454163404704655535315507*t^2)/81129638414606681695789005144064 + (7027663972423957*t)/4503599627370496 + 7`, check the contents of `eq` when reaching the last line. For the four equation there is probably a surrounding `[]` missing but i have no idea what the 2. 3. and 4. line is supposed to do. Please explain what you are trying to solve.

Comment: I don't think you can solve several equations without a for. I am afraid that is likely the answer.

Comment: Edit your question. What is the full error message? Is the second instance of `eq` actually the output returned by the previous line rather than code? If so, clean up your code and make it clear what is what. It's probably a bad idea to use random values in a question without at least setting the seed via `rng` to make things repeatable. It's also a bit silly to use such values a symbolic solver, so I assume they're just for example? Lastly, you only have one unknown. *If* `solve` returns a solution it will be for one or more roots of `t`.